# Remember check box value when re-visited the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 check boxes in my page.  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/1/)

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Scooter">I have a Scooter <br>
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit ">
</form>
```

When the user clicks on "Submit", it navigates to another page. When I visit the same page again, I want to see the values which I previously selected. How can I do that using Javascript?

Comment: you need to store the value some where... in client side using cookie/web storage or in server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a cookie (or some other persistent storage) to store the values of whatever is checked.

With a cookie, you can do this by attaching event listeners to the checkboxes, so that when they are updated (selected/deselected) a cookie is stored (or updated) containing their current values.

When the page initially loads, you will then check for the presence of the cookie and populate the boxes accordingly.

Here's one way you might do it. This uses the [jQuery cookie library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Persist checkboxes</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="checkAll">Check all</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $("#checkAll").on("change", function() {
        $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
      });

      $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
        var checkboxValues = {};
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
          checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
        });
        $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
      });

      function repopulateCheckboxes(){
        var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
        if(checkboxValues){
          Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = checkboxValues[element];
            $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
          });
        }
      }

      $.cookie.json = true;
      repopulateCheckboxes();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shall I have to do Java coding if I implement this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. You can however, copy this example and tailor it to your needs. Please note that this won't work locally with certain browsers (e.g. Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

If it is within the same browser session you can maintain them in sessions.

OR

Set a cookie to remember the selected value

Answer (score 0):

Save it to cookie using `document.cookie` as `key=value` pairs separated by semicolons:

```
document.cookie = "vehicle=Bike; name=Billy;"
```

Then look it up when you build the page